# No reaction to click left mouse button - Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

I have a problem in Windows 11. Randomly, the Laptop stops responding to left mouse button clicks. It doesn't matter if it's a laptop touchpad or another external mouse. After refreshing the system (i can do it with the right mouse button - it works) The reaction to the left mouse button works for some time. Ctrl-alt-delte also helps, but in this menu you can never click with the left button, but moving between options works with keys importantly, whenever the left button stops working while using a laptop, moving using the keyboard works. Done so far: Windows 11 format, disk diagnostics. I have no idea where the problem could be

Comment: Update the firmware (UEFI) if available.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Why would this fix an external mouse?

Comment: @DavidPostill If the problem occurs the same way and simultaneously with the touchpad and external t6hen the problem is not with the external mouse. Updating the firmware in this weird cases is the first troubleshooting step and probably the only one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that some application is stealing the mouse action through a [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks). There are a number of applications that insert themselves into Windows Event handling, such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm). If an exception occurs while handling the event, that *click* could be lost.

- If you are using *AutoHotkey*, *X-Mouse Button Control*, a special driver for the mouse or keypad (e.g., [Synaptics Touchpad driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=756gc)), or a similar application *not* built into Windows OS, try killing it and running for a while without it.

  - If such an app causes an issue, look for scripts and settings that can be changed.
  - Update to the latest version of the driver *for your PC* or the third-party application.
- In *Task Manager*, on the *Details* tab, check carefully for any unknown process that might steal the *click*. BTW, MS/Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can submit processes to *VirusTotal* to check for malware.